# Finding all numeric value from an array of object & perform multiplication or division

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, lodash

I am using ReactJs for building my web application. The application has a state variable which contains the state of the application. My application has a feature where user see three radio buttons (`thousands, millions, actual`). When user clicks `thousands` radio button, I need to show all the numeric values in thousands. Same login apply for millions.

The state variable contains array of object. Each object can have its own sets of properties. Each property can be numeric, object, boolean or string.

What I want: I want to go over each property, check if it is numeric type, if true, divide each value by 1000 in case of thousand radio button is checked (similar logic for million button).

What is the most efficient way to achieve desired result.

Comment: Could paste an example of the state variable and the output that you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

for formatting, use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-number.

In render function of your component, use array.filter to filter out any non-numeric values, then map the result to something like `renderValue` function. In this function, check currently selected formatter, which will be saved in state (I'll get to it in a second) by `this.state.formatter`. Format your value using `format-number` package and your formatter from `this.state.formatter` and display it.

Filtering will look something similar to:
`this.props.values.filter((value) => !isNaN(value)).map(this.renderValue)`

When it comes to setting your formatter to state, create `<Input type="radio" name="format" value={1000} onChange={this.handleChange}/>`and your handleChange function:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
   this.setState({formatter: event.target.value});
}
```